# Sort an array of Dicts in Julia

Tags: arrays, dictionary, sorting, julia

There must be an easy syntax to sort an array (Vector{Dict}) of dictionaries in Julia.  Say I have:

```
3-element Vector{Dict}:

Dict{String, Any}("firstName" =\\\> "roger", "age" =\\\> 45)

Dict{String, Any}("firstName" =\\\> "matt", "age" =\\\> 50)

Dict{String, Any}("firstName" =\\\> "beth", "age" =\\\> 20)
```

How can I sort on "firstName"?

Any help would be appreciated.

I would like to use a native sort method.  This is what I'd like:

```
3-element Vector{Dict}:

Dict{String, Any}("firstName" =\\\> "beth", "age" =\\\> 20)

Dict{String, Any}("firstName" =\\\> "matt", "age" =\\\> 50)

Dict{String, Any}("firstName" =\\\> "roger", "age" =\\\> 45)
```

I have tried all sorts of variations of "sort":

```
sort(Students\\\[:\\\],by=\\\["firstName"\\\])

sort(Students\\\[:\\\],by="firstName")

sort(Students,\\\["firstName"\\\])
```

All of these attempts threw errors.

Comment: what's the deal with all of the backslashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sort!(Students, by = x -> x["firstName"])
```